# so I'm using moment.js to find the time difference from the time coming from the Backend(UTC) and the local time gotten from moment.js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

Now my code works and i get the right time in Local host. The problem is why am i getting an additional 5 hours added in when viewed from the developer portal, is it an env issue ? config issue? what's happening?

below shows is me calculating how much hours/days/months ago has a certain notification been received

```
 const getDayDiff = (timestamp) => {`enter code here`
    let a = moment.utc();
    console.log("from moment", a);
    let b = moment(timestamp);
    console.log("from backend", b);
    let temp = ["year", "month", "days", "hour", "minute", "second"];
    let i = 1;
    do {
      let diff = a.diff(b, temp[i]);

      if (diff !== 0) {
        return `${diff} ${temp[i]} ago`;
      }
      i = i + 1;
    } while (i <= temp.length);
  };
```

and how it'll look when u console loh them[image]

Comment: Please post code and not images of code

Comment: How does the `timestamp` value look like?

Comment: i left a screen shot of how it looks

Comment: what is the *exact*  type and value of `timestamp`?

Comment: depends on where you are at, the type and value. However the server are based in san Diego and im here in sri lanka. so is there a chance that UTC is added ? if i add moment.utc(), should it correct the issue?

Comment: It's for sure that this is a timezone issue. But without knowning your exact input values nobody is able to help you which of your date conversions is going wrong ...

Comment: IST is the time zone from where i'm from. so moment should be getting the time from there. timestamp is coming from a aws server in san Diego

Comment: Again: *In what format is that timestamp coming in????* This is a crucial part of information. Because the format of that timestamp determines HOW momentjs will interpret it. There is major difference in parsing `2021-09-04T12:34:56` and `2021-09-04T12:34:56Z` For your timezone, this difference may be about 5:30 hours ...

Comment: 2021-09-03T10:14:40.007 format. sorry for the delay, got alot of work going. Must be the same case with you so your help is appreciated alot!

Comment: if your `timestamp` parameter really is `2021-09-03T10:14:40.007` your code will work fine and interpet that time as a timestamp in your local timezone and calculate the difference to current time correctly ...

Comment: Btw, you are never calculating the difference in `years` and if the difference is less than a minute, you will probably run into an error, because arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: It works for seconds and thank you for pointing out the years, didn't notice that. Also, what i did gives an incorrect time when viewed through the dev portal? it adds 5 hrs but isn't .utc suppose to prevent it ?